# Guice / DI and mixing injection and parameters passed in at runtime

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I have a situation where when I initialize some of my classes, some of the fields I need to be injected (e.g. references to factories etc) whereas some others are dynamic and created at runtime (e.g. usernames etc). How do I construct such objects using the GUICE framework?
Simply annotating the fields I need injected as `@Inject` doesn't work as they seem to not be set up when creating an object using the constructor. For instance:

```
class C {
   @Inject
   private FactoryClass toBeInjected;

   private ConfigurationField passedIn;

   public C(ConfigurationField passedIn) {
      this.passedIn = passedIn;
   }
}
```

If my understanding is correct (and I could be wrong), the fact that I'm creating a new instance of `C` via `new` and not through Guice means that no injection will take place. I do need to pass these parameters in the constructor, but also want some fields injected -- so how do I solve this problem?

Comment: Have you created a Module class? if it is the case could you provide it?

Comment: @MasterMind please elaborate. I have an abstract module (anonymous inner class) which does some binding but as I understand I don't have to declare every single binding there surely?

Comment: Generally, when i use guice i declare a module which is the central place where i do delcare  the methods (with @Provides annotation) that returns the Object that will be injected (with @Inject) or using configure method of the module to bind a type class with implementation class

Comment: Having a module doesn't solve the problem that when creating `new C(parameters)` the `toBeInjected` doesn't get injected and is left to null.

Comment: Yes but with guice you delegate the management of the instance of object to him and you should tell him where to get the instance: either by @Provides annotation or using bind method. May be i'm wrong but that's how i'm using it

Comment: If my understanding is correct (and I could be wrong), the fact that I'm creating a new instance of `C` via `new` and not through Guice means that no injection will take place. I do need to pass these parameters in the constructor, but also want some fields injected -- so how do I solve this problem?

Comment: This is exactly the work for assisted inject.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A feature specifically matching "mixing injection and parameters passed" would be [Assisted Injection](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/AssistedInject).

```
class C {
  // Guice will automatically create an implementation of this interface.
  // This can be defined anywhere, but I like putting it in the class itself.
  interface Factory {
    C create(ConfigurationField passedIn);
  }

  @Inject
  private FactoryClass toBeInjected;

  private ConfigurationField passedIn;
  private SomeOtherDepIfYoudLike otherDep;

  @Inject public C(@Assisted ConfigurationField passedIn,
      SomeOtherDepIfYoudLike otherDep) {
    this.passedIn = passedIn;
    this.otherDep = otherDep;
  }
}
```

Now in your module:

```
@Override public void configure() {
  install(new FactoryModuleBuilder().build(C.Factory.class));
}
```

Now when someone wants to create a C, they can avoid calling the constructor directly; instead, they inject a C.Factory into which they pass a ConfigurationField instance of their choice and receive a fully-constructed, fully-injected C instance. (Like with most well-designed DI objects, they *can* call the constructor directly.)

Note that this design is especially useful in a few ways:

- You can use constructor injection, treat all your fields as final, and treat the object as immutable.
- If you stick with constructor injection entirely, your object will never be in a partially-initialized state, and your API stays simple (call the constructor and your object is ready).
- For testing, you can write any implementation of `C.Factory` and have it return any instance you want. This can include test doubles of C or its factory: Fakes, mocks, or spies that you create manually or by using Mockito, EasyMock, JMock, or any other mocking framework.

Comment: One question: how can create an object of type C by also specifying the `SomeOtherDepIfYoudLike` dependency? This dependency has to be created by the injector?

Comment: @CosminIoniță Your factory method (`create`, but you can name it however you like) can take multiple parameters, which each get the annotation `@Assisted` in the constructor. If all of your constructor parameters are assisted, or none of your parameters are assisted, then you don't need assisted injection—you can just use a normal constructor.

Answer (score 3):

#### What you are looking for is "On Demand" Injections:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(...);
    CreditCardProcessor creditCardProcessor = new PayPalCreditCardProcessor();
    injector.injectMembers(creditCardProcessor);
}
```

or for static things

```
@Override public void configure() {
   requestStaticInjection(ProcessorFactory.class);
   ...
 }
```

All explained very well https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Injections#on-demand-injection.

#### Note:

> Both of these things are code smells and should only really be used
> for migrating old code over to Guice. New code should not use these
> approaches.

Comment: I think I understand now -- the idea is to move from usage of `new` to factories/builders and then inject these across as per your comment.

Comment: I'd like to stress that `injectMembers`/`requestStaticInjection` is explicitly *not* the preferred way to pass "runtime" dependencies to injectable objects. As the quote you provided says, it should only be used with the code which is not adapted for injection and which can't be changed. Assisted inject should be used for new code.